# Composer not installing dependencies of Package

Tags: php, json, github, zend-framework2, composer-php

I have two projects. One is my `application` and the second one is an `external module` that I want to use in future apps.

I have created my external module on GitHub and included in the `composer.json` of my application.

My `external module` gets **downloaded** / **cloned** but the `required dependencies are not installed by composer`.

**Here's composer.json of my application:**

```
{
    "name": "application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
        "zf-commons/zfc-user": "1.4.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "~0.9.2",
        "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": "1.0.*",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "^0.0.2",
        "username/GlideUser": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/username/GlideUser.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Here's composer.json of my external module:**

```
{
    "name": "username/glide-user",
    "description": "Module For Zend Framework 2",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/username/GlideUser",
    "keywords": [
        "zf2",
        "zfc-user",
        "bjyauthorize"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Haris Mehmood",
            "email": "abc@outlook.com",
            "homepage": "abc.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize": "1.4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "GlideUser\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run **composer install** or **composer update** I expect bjyauthorize package to gets installed, but composer ignore the dependency and install everything else.

What is it that I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating the following line in your application composer.json from:

```
"username/GlideUser": "dev-master"
```

to:

```
"username/glide-user": "dev-master"
```

This way, what is being required matches the name of the external module, which is the name defined inside the external module's composer.json.

Although it does not look directly applicable to the dependencies of the external module not installing, it could be the cause.

Comment: This worked! Thanks Ben Plummer, or should I call you Ben Plumber, since you fix broken things ;) Thanks alot.

Comment: Haha, no problem! Glad I could help :)